# Why is it that not the entire surface of Earth is covered by water?

Tags: water, earth, geophysics

Isn't it a coincidence that our planet is mostly but not completely covered by water? Is there a reason why less water or more water is not compatible with intelligent life?

Also, isn't it a coincidence that the increasing amount of surface water on Earth (I assume that originally Earth was dry) had the same time-scale as the evolution of life?

Is it correct that water quantity is constantly increasing and eventually the whole planet will be covered by water?

**added:** reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_of_water_on_Earth

Comment: Where should the water come from?

Comment: This appears to be off topic

Comment: Are you asking why we are not a water planet, i.e. completely covered? In order to do that we would need a sufficient amount of information about earth-like exoplanets, which we don't have, yet. The average formation conditions of such planets in the universe are not sufficiently known to make any judgement on these topics and that is also true for anything related to the existence of intelligent life. Science is mum about these questions, even though humans in general like to speculate quite a bit. As for our water... Earth will be dry within 1-1.5 billion years, or so.

Comment: It's not clear what this question is asking. Why should the *"water quantity"* be *"constantly increasing"* and what "coincidence" are you talking about?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Earth Science.

Comment: I can only speculate that the question is inspired by the fact that comets and other such space debris are constantly bringing (small amounts) of water to Earth.

Answer (score 2):

The omnipresence of water on Earth is a product of the conditions and matter present on Earth when it began to form billions of years ago. You could call it a coincidence.
It is not correct that the amount of water on earth is constantly increasing. Water levels are currently rising, but because of glaciers melting, not because water is somehow being created. Once all the ice melts the water level will stop rising, and remain constant, all other factors being equal. 
As for whether more or less water is incompatible with life, there's not a satisfactory answer yet. There's no evidence that life can exist without water being present in some quantity, but that's because the only place that we know can support life is covered in water. If we find life on a dry planet, then things get exciting, but until then 100% of biology depends on the presence of water.

Comment: My reasoning is based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_of_water_on_Earth where it's said that water on earth comes from outer space